# Remote Desktop Connection on Local office connection

Tags: windows-7, remote-control

I can't connect to a local server on my office Network.
pinging doesn't return (request timed out)or 
destination host unreachable.

other computers connected to the same switch as i am, can connect to the server and is totally fine so I've checked on the server. And the server also can't connect to my computer,
pinging doesn't return any requests also.

I can connect to other outside servers with remote connection just fine, only this server i can't connect to.
I think it might be my firewall or antivirus blocking the connection but so far i couldn't find anything on my firewall blocking me.
which side could be blocking the connection ? and how do i connect
Any suggestions ?

Comment: One question that springs to mind is: can your machine ping the other hosts on the local network, and vice versa?  Also, have you looked at the IP addresses to ensure that they are sane?

Comment: yes i have pinged others and it worked normally. Just couldn't ping that server
and ping myself from the server.